# Requisição de json para tableview com rolagem lenta

Tags: json, swift, assincronismo

Tenho uma aplicação que retorna um json para uma tableview, porém, cada vez que rolo as células ele dá meio que umas "engasgadas", já me disseram que teria que deixar a função de retorno do json assíncrona... Alguém sabe como tratar isso em Swift?

São apenas 10 linhas com imagem e ao lado uma label, porém com testes feitos, vih que o problema de lentidão é só com o carregamento das imagens que tem nas celulas no método cellForRowAtIndexPath se eu comentar a partir da linha que pega a url das imagens até o final fica de boa, é como se o método CellForAtIndexPath fizesse toda requisição das imagens a cada rolagem.

A parte do código que ta com pro...

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell:Cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Cell


        cell.info.text = arrayJson[indexPath.row]
        cell.info.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12.0)

        if let url = NSURL(string: self.arrayJsonImages[indexPath.row]) {

             let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)

                cell.imagem.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
                cell.imagem.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                cell.imagem.layer.masksToBounds = true;
                cell.imagem.layer.cornerRadius = 15;

        }


            return cell


    }
```

Comment: Você esta populando com muitos dados? Porque geralmente criamos uma "limitação". Tavelz seja isto, mas faltam detalhes pra ter certeza do teu problema.

Comment: Já editei a pergunta, creio que ficou mais claro agora...

Comment: Amigo desculpe mas continua dificil de entender o que "você fez" exatamente, recomendo que leia isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - tenho certeza que vai entender isto como uma critica construtiva :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De fato você vai precisar fazer o download assíncrono desta imagem para que não dê estas travadas em sua tabela.

Comece com algo assim:

```
if let imageUrl = NSURL(string: arrayJsonImages[indexPath.row]) {
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: imageUrl)
    let requestQueue : NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: requestQueue, completionHandler: { (response, responseData, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            cell.image = UIImage(data: responseData!)
        }
    })
}
```

Isso já resolve o seu problema de travamento. Agora, para otimizar ainda mais, seria interessante armazenar estas imagens em um diretório de *cache*, assim não vai ser necessário fazer download toda vez, caso seja este o seu caso.

Se quiser algo mais robusto, um *"placeholder"*, o próprio gerenciamento de *cache* e etc, você pode buscar algo já pronto como por exemplo a [*SDWebImage*](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), que é uma *category* da `UIImageView`.